# How to write leaner Codable Structs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

My question is concerning Structs.

**Current Situation:**

I have a JSON object that is read from the file system. There are 3 things about this data.

1. The root level keys, i.e. `notConcerned0ne` and `notConcernedTwo` are only known at runtime.
2. The second level properties are known, ie. `PredeterminedOne` and `PredeterminedTwo` and known, also the descendant properties are known.

```
{
    "notConcerned0ne": {
        "PredeterminedOne": {
            "label": "blue",
            "description": "something..."
        }
    },
    "notConcernedTwo": {
        "PredeterminedTwo": {
            "label": "green",
            "description": "something..."
        }
    }
}
```

I have simplified my data, in reality, there will be at least 20 Predetermined properties.

The following works just fine. But given that I will have many more predetermined properties, I'm searching for a solution to reduce the duplicate structs which do the same thing.

```swift
// working

struct Domain: Codable {
    let notConcerned0Ne: NotConcerned0Ne
    let notConcernedTwo: NotConcernedTwo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case notConcerned0Ne = "notConcerned0ne"
        case notConcernedTwo = "notConcernedTwo"
    }
}


struct NotConcerned0Ne: Codable {
    let predeterminedOne: Predetermined

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case predeterminedOne = "PredeterminedOne"
    }
}


struct Predetermined: Codable {
    let label, predeterminedDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case label
        case predeterminedDescription = "description"
    }
}


struct NotConcernedTwo: Codable {
    let predeterminedTwo: Predetermined

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case predeterminedTwo = "PredeterminedTwo"
    }
}
```

The following is my attempt is to reduce the duplication code.

```swift
struct Domain: Codable {
    let notConcerned0Ne, notConcernedTwo: NotConcernedShared

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case notConcerned0Ne = "notConcerned0ne"
        case notConcernedTwo = "notConcernedTwo"
    }
}


struct NotConcernedShared: Codable {
    let predeterminedOne, predeterminedTwo: Predetermined

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case predeterminedOne = "PredeterminedOne"
        case predeterminedTwo = "PredeterminedTwo"
    }
}


struct Predetermined: Codable {
    let label, predeterminedDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case label
        case predeterminedDescription = "description"
    }
}
```

But this presents an error

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "PredeterminedTwo", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "notConcerned0ne", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"PredeterminedTwo\", intValue: nil) (\"PredeterminedTwo\").", underlyingError: nil))`

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "PredeterminedTwo", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "notConcerned0ne", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"PredeterminedTwo\", intValue: nil) (\"PredeterminedTwo\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Please can you help out and point me to something specific about the codable protocol that I am clearly missing. Or in the way that I'm forming the structs.

Also, perhaps I could remove the root level keys and do a `typealias TheDomain = [String: Domain]` since I dont care about the root level property names.

Incase you wish to see, my load function works fine.

```swift
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear: do you care about `PredeterminedOne` and the others? Do you want them in the final struct, or do you really just want an array of label/description structs? (What would be your ideal final data structure if you could have anything you want from this input?) Can there be a bunch of Predetermined keys inside of a NotConcerned, or is there always just one. (Do you care what the Predetermined is?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your json as a dictionary of dictionaries where the inner dictionaries uses `Predetermined` as value

```
let values = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String: Predetermined]].self, from: data)
    .map(\.value)
```

Then you can easily look up the right element for "PredeterminedOne/Two"

If you don't care about "PredeterminedOne/Two" (I was uncertain about this) then you can use `.flatMap` as well to directly get an array of `Predetermined`, just add it to the code above

```
let values = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String: Predetermined]].self, from: data)
    .map(\.value)
    .flatMap(\.values)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.

I use a Generic type for loading function 

I'll paste the generic load function. 

I then simply call my "load"  function passing in the file name.

` @Published var myData: Domain = load("theData.json")` 

Perhaps I am

Comment: No problem using that function, you can apply `.map` (and `.flatMap`) on the returned value

Comment: @meteorBuzz so did this help you with your issue?